# WSO2 Data Service query: Cannot use top level array in JSON output format?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm creating a data service in EI 6.4.0 and having trouble getting the JSON output for a query formatted how I want it. This query returns multiple rows and I would like the JSON formatted like this:

```
{
  results: [{
    fieldA: $fieldB,
    fieldB: $fieldB
  }]
}
```

However, that format causes an error when I deploy the service to carbon. Instead, I'm forced to add another object "layer" to the response:

```
{
  results: {
    result: [{
      fieldA: $fieldB,
      fieldB: $fieldB
    }]
  }
}
```

Why is this? It's really silly, because this second layer is completely useless. It's really annoying when using [nested queries](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Defining+Nested+Queries) too.

Answer (score 0):

By design, WSO2 does not allow the former mentioned output mapping. What I would suggest is to add a proxy service, call the dataservice and transform the resulting json to the desired one.

You can just add a payload mediator to achieve that:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>
      {
        results: $1
      }
    </format>
        <args>
           <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.results.result"/>
        </args>
</payloadFactory>
```